# Angular2 creating and using classes

Tags: angular, class, typescript

I have this simple class:
copiadorabusqueda.model.ts:

```
import { ClienteModel } from './cliente.model';
import { ContratoModel } from './contrato.model';
import { ProveedorModel } from './proveedor.model';
import { MarcaModel } from './marca.model';
import { ModeloModel } from './modelo.model';

interface ICopiadoraBusquedaModel {
    codigoCopiadora: string; // text
    numeroSerie: string; // select (primitive)
    numeroInventario: string; // select (object)
    nombrePersonaEncargada: string; // multiple select
    cliente: ClienteModel;
    contrato: ContratoModel;
    proveedor: ProveedorModel;
    marca: MarcaModel;
    modelo: ModeloModel;
}

export class CopiadoraBusquedaModel implements ICopiadoraBusquedaModel {
    public codigoCopiadora: string;
    public numeroSerie: string;
    public numeroInventario: string;
    public nombrePersonaEncargada: string;
    public cliente: ClienteModel;
    public contrato: ContratoModel;
    public proveedor: ProveedorModel;
    public marca: MarcaModel;
    public modelo: ModeloModel;
    constructor() {  }
}
```

From my component:

```
import { CopiadoraBusquedaModel } from  './copiadorabusqueda.model';
import { ClienteModel } from './cliente.model';
import { ProveedorModel } from './proveedor.model';
import { ContratoModel } from './contrato.model';
import { MarcaModel } from './marca.model';
import { ModeloModel } from './modelo.model';


//... some stuff ...


  export class BusquedaCopiadorasComponent {       
    private copiadoraBusquedaModel: CopiadoraBusquedaModel = new CopiadoraBusquedaModel();

    //... some stuff ..

    rellenarCopiadoraBusquedaModel() {
        this.copiadoraBusquedaModel.nombrePersonaEncargada = "HELLO WORLD";

    }
```

when I ask for "this.copiadoraBusquedaModel" from my component, its return undefined. the models are correctly imported from my component. ¿Any idea?

Comment: Because you didn't pass any value inside constructor of your class `CopiadoraBusquedaModel` while creating new instance `new CopiadoraBusquedaModel()`

Comment: I don´t pass any value inside constructor because in my class "CopiadoraBusquedaModel" is empty. When I am creating a new instance I do not want to pass the values at that moment, is this posible?

Comment: when did you  exactly called the method `rellenarCopiadoraBusquedaModel` ?

Comment: When i do click over button:  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonBuscar" (click)="rellenarCopiadoraBusquedaModel($event)">

Comment: I solved it, removing the constructor setence from my model. Thank you anyway